# jquery getting and passing href to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having some problems getting the href of the clicked element and passing it to a function, this is something i have not done before so done my best but have not got it. Any ideas?

```
$('#smoke_confirm').click(function(e){
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            tstconfirm(href);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        function tstconfirm(href){
            smoke.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?',function(e){
                if (e){
                    window.location = $(href);
                }
            }, {cancel:"cancel", ok:"confirm"});
        }
```

Comment: The problem is too much jQuery ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

href here is  a text so `$(href)` is not correct as it will try to select element with the href value. Just do `window.location = href`. Also if you just want to get the href you dont need to create a jquery instance of `this` you could just do `this.href` which is a DOM element property.

```
$('#smoke_confirm').click(function(e){
            var href = this.href;
            tstconfirm(href);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        function tstconfirm(href){
            smoke.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?',function(e){
                if (e){
                    window.location = href;
                }
            }, {cancel:"cancel", ok:"confirm"});
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a load! knew i was almost there with it :)

Comment: @1Line you are welcome. yes you were, Just some minor hiccup.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`href` is a string

```
 window.location = $(href); // This will try to convert it to a jQuery object
```

supposed to be

```
 window.location = href;
```